# algebra to html converter

Tags: java, html, math, algebra

These are some sample algebraic equations

```
2x = 3
3x + 5 = 8
(y+1)/7 = (y-2)/3
```

Is there a java API which you can use to create such equations using a java program and return an equivalent HTML which in turn can be used for rendering purposes.

Comment: Do you accept formula images (like PNG or GIF links) instead of HTML markup?

Comment: @SHiNKiROU would like to know what kind of options are available to generate images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need a client side or server side solution?

Client side:

1. [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML)
2. [MathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org/)
3. (old) [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/)

Server side:

The best typesetter for math is, hands down, LaTeX.

Here is a Java LaTeX interface: http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/

Comment: MathML is worth a try but - beware - not all browser can render MathML out of the box. AFAIK, Internet Explorer needs a special plugin. LaTeX based solution require server side rendering and display images on the web pages.

Comment: Guess, I am looking for a server side interface

Comment: Don't forget MathJAX, the successor to jsMath.  No server-side LaTeX required, compatible with most browsers, very nice rendering (often without having to generate server-side images, so the equations will resize nicely even if you change the browser's font size).

Answer (score 1):

you really need to provide more info.

The first answer i have for use is: String,

```
 String equation ="2x = 3";
```

What extra formating do you need ?
Otherwise again its very simple

```
<html><body>2x = 3</body>/<html>
```

Pretty sure you need something else but no idea what.

Besides that you can use JEP to hava Java parse fomulas http://www.singularsys.com/jep/

Comment: The given equations are just simple ones, for complex equations it might not be possible to manipulate the object via a String. Hence my question on a higher level abstraction